# Is it possible to include only required properties in context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, ef-code-first

I have Extension for my EF context to inlcude all the Properties of `Mission`Entity that have `RequiredAttribute`:

```
public static IQueryable<Mission> MissionWithRequired(this IDbContext context)
{
   return context.Missions
             .Include(mission => mission.Theme)
             .Include(mission => mission.Contact)
             .Include(mission => mission.Editor);
}
```

Its works fine.

The idea to refactor it - to make it possible to use not only with `Missions` but also with other Entities.

My first step is to read the Properties that are marked with `RequiredAttribute` using `Reflection`. But it doesnt work:

```
public static IQueryable<Mission> MissionWithRequired(this IOrgDatenbankContext context)
{
   var requiredProperties = typeof(Mission).GetProperties()
            .Where(property => Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(RequiredAttribute)));

   foreach (var requiredProperty in requiredProperties)
   {
      context.Missions.Include(requiredProperty.Name);
   }

   return context.Missions;
}
```

The `context` contains `Missions` but not `Theme`, `Contract` and `Editor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving each include to a local variable (sorry but I am unable to verify this works)

```
public static IQueryable<Mission> MissionWithRequired(this IOrgDatenbankContext context)
{
   var requiredProperties = typeof(Mission).GetProperties()
            .Where(property => Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(RequiredAttribute)));

   IQueryable<Mission> result = context.Missions;
   foreach (var requiredProperty in requiredProperties)
   {
      result = result.Include(requiredProperty.Name);
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: thnaks for you post. What will I achieve with storing the information in local variable?

Comment: You should get the **compound** result of all your `Include`'s. `Include()` doesn't do anything by itself, it returns a modified instance of `IQueryable`. In your first code example you call `Include`, passing the modified `IQueryable` on to the 2nd `Include` etc with the fluent API. In the second code example you do nothing with the modified `IQueryable` that is returned from the call to `Include`.

Comment: upvote =) I ll try it next days - cause some other parts of code should also be updated.. Ill give my feedback after it.